# Spring application context

Tags: java, spring

Is there any other way in J6SE to get spring (spring 3.0) application context than implement `ApplicationContextAware` interface?

Sorry I must improve my question. I have running application context in my J6SE app and in some classes I need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading your question, I know you're looking for an alternative to ApplicationContextAware but I read it that you have a goal of many classes using the ApplicationContext but want to avoid implementing the interface for all these classes.  This approach still uses the ApplicationContextAware but encapsulates it into a single class for reuses.

I typically load the configuration at application start up via a ContextLoaderListener in the web.xml.  After this occurs, I set "MyApplicationContext" as the contextApplicationContextProvider.

```
<bean id="contextApplicationContextProvider" class="pkg.MyApplicationContext"></bean>
```

The class must implement ApplicationContextAware as you already suggested:

```
public class MyApplicationContext implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext appContext;

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware#setApplicationContext(org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext)
     */
    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext globalAppContext)
        throws BeansException {

        this.appContext = globalAppContext;

    }

    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return appContext;
    }

}
```

The key here is that you now have a static reference to the single instance of the ApplicationContext object.  Retrieving it is simple by using the static method call MyApplicationContext.getApplicationContext() for any class, spring-managed or not.

Comment: Yes I have this implemented like singleton. But I have idea to provide daos of classes in enum type, and I need to setup the app. context in this enum. I don't like the way to using my singleton in this enum.

Comment: If I understand this properly, you'd like an Enum to be injected with DAOs.  Given Enums are static by nature, I don't believe the Spring IoC can manage these beans and therefore inject anything.  Accessing the application context view from a static Singleton is the only way I'm aware of reaching this goal.

Answer (score 0):

You can load it from the CLASSPATH.

Answer (score 0):

```
new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(APPLICATION_CONTEXT_FILE);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Inject
private ApplicationContext ctx;
```

(or `@Autowired` instead of `@Inject`). This is the annotation replacement of `ApplicationContextAware`. This of course mean that the objects needs to be a spring bean.